# Nasm program segmentation fault

Tags: linux, stack, segmentation-fault, arguments, nasm

I am trying to understand the stack in nasm better, so I made this program to try to pass "arguments" to a "function" in nasm. I am very new to this assembly.

```
section .data
v0s0msg0:       db 'Enter something',10
v1t0msg0L:      equ $-v0s0msg0

section .bss
v2i0inp0        resb 256
v3v0temp0   resb 256

section .text
global _start
_start:
;This is a nasm program to help me understand the stack better
mov eax,4
mov ebx,1
mov ecx,v0s0msg0
mov edx,v1t0msg0L
int 80h

mov eax,3
mov ebx,0
mov ecx,v2i0inp0
mov edx,256
int 80h

push dword v2i0inp0
call f0m0test0

mov eax,1
mov ebx,0
int 80h

f0m0test0:
pop dword[v3v0temp0]
mov eax,4
mov ebx,1
mov ecx,v3v0temp0
mov edx,256
int 80h
ret 4
```

I can assemble it, link it, and run it just fine, but when running it, after I enter the input, it just says segmentation fault following two '?' looking characters.

I've tried changing

```
pop dword[v3v0temp0]
```

to something like:

```
pop v3v0temp0
```

or even:

```
mov v3v0temp0,dword[ebp]
```

and many things like that, but they all end up as either segmentation faults, or as an error in the assembler saying:
    invalid combination of opcode and operands
I would really appreciate help to make this program work, also, please explain a little bit about the stack, using the prefix 'dword', and what the '[]' characters are for. I would like an explanation just of how to use the stack for "arguments".
I am running this on a linux os, Ubuntu
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

```
f0m0test0:
pop dword[v3v0temp0]
```

This pops the return address off the stack, not the parameter.

```
mov eax,4
mov ebx,1
mov ecx,v3v0temp0
mov edx,256
int 80h
ret 4
```

Since you've already `pop`ed something (though not the intended parameter) off stack, `ret 4` above is almost definitely wrong.

I think you want just:

```
f0m0test0:
mov eax,4
mov ebx,1
mov ecx,[esp+4]
mov edx,256
int 80h
ret 4
```

Alternatively, instead of the callee cleaning up the parameter with `ret 4`, have the caller do it (which, I believe, is the usual calling convention):

```
push dword v2i0inp0
call f0m0test0
add esp,4
```